# html5 play video chrome problems PC

Tags: jquery, windows, html, google-chrome, video

I have a problem with html5 video in chrome on Windows.
The Video ist playing fine. But if it ends, the video doesn't fadeout. Instead of fading out, the "divx" icon shows and nothing happens. It seems that chrome doesnt notice that the video ends.

If I set the video in a loop, the video loops all the time in Chrome (on Mac everything works fine on all browsers / also in firefox on Win).

here is my javascrip:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var video = $('video')[0];
                video.addEventListener('ended', function () {
                    $('video').fadeOut(200);
                }, false);
                video.play();     
            });
        </script>
```

heres my html:

```
<video id="video" autoplay preload>
            <source src="animation/animation.mp4" width="100%" height="100%" type="video/mp4";>
            <source src="animation/Komp.ogv" width="100%" height="100%" type="video/ogg";>
</video>
```

I would be very glad if someone can help me.

Comment: every where you're using reference of $('video')[0] to refer to the element except inside the event listener...see maybe that is the problem.

Comment: or change the reference inside to $(this).fadeOut(200);

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks for your help guys.**
I fixed it finally with disabling the Divx-Webplayer plugin. The video didn't react on fadeOut or hide or something like that. Without the plugin everything works fine!